# Querying for an Unrelated model field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm a newbie on rails. How to query for a non related model field. Say I've a billing model where I need to fetch the product group while I store only product_code in the billing model. I'm using acts as api. I need to send all product_codes along with product group which is not at all related to billing model.

Thank You
Sai

Comment: How is your billing model related with product groups?

Comment: billing model has billing_item and each billed_item is stored with a product_code. There is no association other than directly storing. We're  not using product_id  to store, but a product_code.

Comment: Not sure how you are relating your product_code's to product group, but as I understand your original post - you want to essentially get all the product_codes for each billing_item?

Comment: No, I store product_code in billing_item fields and I need product group for along with each billing_item . By the way products are related as follows `belongs_to :product_group, :class_name => "ProductGroup" ` in Products and `has_many :products , :class_name => "Product"` in ProductGroups

Answer (score 1):

Consider,

```
Billing.each do |r|
  product = Product.find(r.billing_item)
  product_group = product.product_group
end
```

Of course `product_group` above would be an AR association, you'd need to grab whatever appropriate attribute of your ProductGroup, i.e. name or title for example.

Comment: Sincerly appreciate your help, but Won't it be an expensive query?

Comment: `I need to send all product_codes along with product group which is not at all related to billing model` - Well your question didn't discuss that aspect =)  Look into eager loading but since your models are pretty isolated I'm not sure if there's a better approach.  You could limit the resulting queries if you were to perform this on a single Billing record.  Accept my answer when time permits thanks.